# Laravel 6 with Vue.js and webpack instead of regular Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I created a new Laravel project with the `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel FullStack` command.

Afterwards I ran `composer require laravel/ui` command.
Then the `npm install` and `npm run dev` commands
.
And I expect my app.js file to look like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');



Vue.component('videoup', require('./components/VideoUpload.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

However I have this code in my app.js file:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
```

How do I setup Laravel 6 with Vue.js for full stack development?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Laravel Mix documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix

Comment: Why do I have to use webpack to begin with? I just want to apply Vue.js to my laravel 6 application

Comment: You can make it on your own with scaffolding. It would take more time and effort, though. Also, may I ask why you wouldn't want webpack involved into your project?

Comment: because none of the tutorials I come across use webpack

Comment: There is nothing to ask about webpack since laravel mix does all the work for you. It just adds up scalability to your application javascript. I'd suggest you need nothing to worry about. It even prevents getting your code stolen, only partly though. 

Although, you might be interested in pusher's tutorial: https://blog.pusher.com/web-application-laravel-vue-part-1/

You can carry it on from the beginning until the last part to make yourself clear about how it actually works.